# Extracting value from soap response using XPath (?)

Tags: xml, xpath, soap

I want to extract the value of "partref" and "risikonr" in the below soap response. How to I refer it with xpath? (if that is what to use)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP- 
 ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <e:HentRisikoOversiktResponse 
    xmlns:e="urn:tryg:forsikring:tjenester:engasjement">
     <ef:engasjementOversiktRisikoer 
       xmlns:ef="urn:gjensidige:forsikring:engasjement">
        <ef:risikogrupper>
           <ef:risikogruppe>
              <ef:beskrivelse>Bygning</ef:beskrivelse>
              <ef:risikoer>
                 <ef:risiko>
                    <ef:partref>0005721478</ef:partref>
                    <ef:forsikringnr>30439384</ef:forsikringnr>
                   ******
              </ef:risikoer>
           </ef:risikogruppe>
        </ef:risikogrupper>
     </ef:engasjementOversiktRisikoer>
  </e:HentRisikoOversiktResponse>
```

Comment: See no `"risikonr"` in source. Did you mean `"forsikringnr"`?

Comment: jep, that is correct

Comment: and partref also

Comment: `//risiko/(partref|forsikringnr)/text()` ?

Comment: did not work also tried

Comment: .check(xpath("//risiko/partref/text()").saveAs("partref")))

Comment: not working....

Comment: there are also several nodes of type <risiko> and i want to choose the first but I have allereday tried //risiko/partref[0]/text()"

Comment: You should take namespaces into account. Also the first node is not `node[0]`, but `node[1]`

Comment: what do you mean by take namespace into account?

Comment: not working either:

Comment: .check(xpath("/SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/HentRisikoOversiktResponse/engasjementOversiktRisikoer/risikogrupper/risikogruppe/risikoer/risiko/partref[1]").saveAs("partref")))